# How can I search for a specific text element?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

How can I search for the element containing `Click Here to Enter a New Password` using `Nokigiri::HTML`?

My HTML structure is like:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="20" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="bodyContent" valign="top">
      <div>
        <strong>Welcome to</strong>
        <h2 style="margin-top:0">OddZ</h2>
        <a href="http://mandrillapp.com/track/click.php?...">Click Here</a>
        to Enter a New Password
        <p>
          Click this link to enter a new Password. This link will expire within 24 hours, so don't delay.
          <br>
        </p>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried:

```
doc = (Nokogiri::HTML(@inbox_emails.first.body.raw_source))

password_container = doc.search "[text()*='Click Here to Enter a New Password']"
```

but this did not find a result.  When I tried:

```
password_container = doc.search "[text()*='Click Here']"
```

I got no result.

I want to search the complete text.

I found there are many spaces before text `"             to Enter a New Password"` but I have not added any space in the HTML code.

Comment: I don't usually touch code when editing, but the `<a>` "href" was ridiculously long and needed to be truncated for readability.

Answer (score 2):

Much of the text you are searching for is outside of the `a` element.

The best you can do might be:

```
a = doc.search('a[text()="Click Here"]').find{|a| a.next.text[/to Enter a New Password/]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a mix of xpath and regex, but since there's no `matches` in xpath for nokogiri yet, you can implement your own as follows:

```
class RegexHelper
  def content_matches_regex node_set, regex_string
    ! node_set.select { |node| node.content =~ /#{regex_string}/mi }.empty?
  end

  def content_matches node_set, string
    content_matches_regex node_set, string.gsub(/\s+/, ".*?")
  end
end

search_string = "Click Here to Enter a New Password"

matched_nodes = doc.xpath "//*[content_matches(., '#{search_string}')]", RegexHelper.new
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try by using CSS selector. I've saved your HTML as a file called, `test.html`

```
require 'Nokogiri'

@doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('test.html'))

puts @result = @doc.css('p').text.gsub(/\n/,'')
```

it returns

```
Click this link to enter a new Password. This link will expire within 24 hours, so don't delay.
```

There's a good post about [Parsing HTML with Nokogiri](http://ruby.bastardsbook.com/chapters/html-parsing/#h-2-2)

Comment: You want to be very careful using `@doc.css('p').text`. `css` returns a NodeSet, similar to an array, which `text` will iterate over, returning ALL text found inside all the nodes in the NodeSet. This is very unlikely to be what you want, and will cause unexpected results. Instead, use `at` or `at_css` to retrieve just the node you are looking for. In a typical HTML document there will be many different `<p>` tags, so it's easy to imagine how wrong the results could be.

Comment: @theTinMan Thanks a lot. I'm still new to ruby and nokogiri . I'll try to look into more deeply.

Answer (score 0):

You were close. Here's how you find the text's containing element:

```
doc.search('*[text()*="Click Here"]')
```

This gives you the `<a>` tag. Is this what you want? If you actually want the *parent* element of the `<a>`, which is the containing `<div>`, you can modify it like so:

```
doc.search('//*[text()="Click Here"]/..').text
```

This selects the containing `<div>`, the text of which is:

```
Welcome to
OddZ
Click Here
to Enter a New Password

Click this link to enter a new Password. This link will expire within 24 hours, so don't delay.
```